# Console window disappear immediately

Tags: c#, console, stability

Console window is not stable in visual studio using c#. `ReadLine()` is not working also. window disappear immediately and I can not see results.

Comment: Can you include your code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following line after your code:

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

This will prevent the console from executing the next line until you press any key. In your case, it will simply finish running the code.

Comment: `ReadLine()` will wait for `Enter`. `ReadKey()` will wait for any key at all. how does that help?